# Typing Break in Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, typing-break

I installed Ubuntu 12.04, and loathe the new interface so much I've switched to Xubuntu with sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop.

Very happy with that so far. But the typing break I always used to have set is part of gnome.

Is there an equivalent typing break app in xubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

Synaptic lists a package called `xwrits`:

The download is 91.7 kB and there don't seem to be any additional dependencies listed for me on **Lubuntu** 12.10. So I'm assuming the same should hold true for you.

Even `apt-get install -s xwrits` doesn't indicate any dependencies.

Here's what the description says:

> xwrits helps you prevent repetitive stress injury.
>
> xwrits is a small reminder program designed to let you know it is time
> to take a break from typing to rest your wrists and prevent any damage
> to your wrists (or at least make them feel better if you've already
> damaged them). Normally works on the honor system, but if you find
> yourself unable to stop typing during your break, it can also lock your
> keyboard.

I have no idea whether this will meet your needs!